# Data compression for ADO.NET data services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, gzip, wcf-data-services

I have an ADO.NET data service exposed by a .NET app (not IIS) which is consumed by a .NET client app. Some calls to this data service return large amounts of data.

I'd like to compress the XML data on the wire to reduce payload and improve performance. Is this possible?

Comment: Since ado.net data services works over http, does this mean that your app is running an embedded http server? This doesn't sound like a standard setup. Is asp.net involved at all? You'll probably need to give a lot more technical details for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you're [hosting using WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668805.aspx) in your .NET "app"? If so, you would need write some custom [`MessageEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder.aspx) implementation because WCF does not provide this out of the box. Luckily there is [a sample in the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) that you can use.

I actually just realized that this is only step one of two depending on whether or not your client is also WCF? While this will encode the message, it would require that your client be using a similarly configured decoder because that implementation will *not* set the HTTP headers that are necessary to signal that encoding has occurred to a "pure" HTTP client. So, if it's not a WCF client on the other side, in addition to encoding the message itself, you would need to use the `WebOperationContext` to apply the appropriate `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. Unfortunately you cannot do this within the `MessageEncoder` implementation itself because it's too late in the process because by the time the `MessageEncoder` is asked to write the message contents the message frame, in this case the HTTP headers, has already been written. So, you would also need additional behavior, in the form of an [`IOperationBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.ioperationbehavior.aspx), applied to your operations that sets the headers accordingly.

Comment: Of course. Sorry, typo, I meant to write "message encod*er*", not "message "encod*ing*".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to compress and decompress it.

Comment: If you click the link. You see examples on how to compress a byte array

Comment: Yes, but how do I compress the messages passed via ADO.NET data services?

Comment: I think you'll have to get ahold of the raw XML data that the ADO.Net data services class sends out, I'm sure there is a way to intercept this. But what you do is get the XML data, turn it to an array of bytes and then compress it and send it over the wire.. the receiver must also be aware of this and such however and intercept the receiving of the XML data.

Comment: Its pretty obvious that you need to gzip you message body, but that far from solves the problem of getting a hold of the message body at the right time in the request/response.