# GZip complete asp.net website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asmx, gzip

i am making a SPA(Single page application) so, the size of javascript is very huge - 300 KB. Webservices (.asmx files) which make jsdebug files- 350 KB and the aspx files - 123 KB, so, a whole bundle of over 700 KB which makes my website very bulky.

Please tell me the complete procedure to minify and gzip and to use it effectively.

Answer (score 4):

The **[Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/)** enables you to improve the performance of your web applications by **reducing** the size of your `Cascading Style Sheets` and `JavaScript files`.

Following are some good blog links to what you want:

[**How to GZip on ASP.NET**](http://jeeshenlee.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/how-to-gzip-on-asp-net-and-godaddy/)

[**Enabling GZip and Deflate HTTP Compression in ASP.NET pages**](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2007110401&page=1)

[**Enabling dynamic compression**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to reduce size of gzip asmx files

Comment: please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377106/asp-net-webservice-handling-gzip-compressed-request