# Supporting compressed request body with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I need to implement an endpoint that can accept a POST message with a gzip-compressed request *body* (not, *not* a compressed response body).

I found a way to handle this pretty easily by marking the request DTO with `IRequiresRequestStream`, and using `GZipStream` in the service class to decompress the raw request body and construct a string representing the decompressed data. It's a plain text request body, so in this case there's nothing lost by skipping automatic request DTO deserialization.

This is fine, I could stop there, but
I was thinking about whether I could write this in a generic way so that every request posted to ServiceStack could be decompressed if it has the `Content-Encoding` header set correctly. I wrote a `PreRequestFilter` that was looking pretty good, until I ran into a problem: I can't find a way to modify the original request input stream or otherwise ensure that deserialization and other code later in the pipeline can access the decompressed bytes instead of the compressed data:

```
public static void Decompress(IRequest request, IResponse response)
{
    if (!request.Headers[HttpHeaders.ContentEncoding].EqualsIgnoreCase(CompressionTypes.GZip))
        return;

    request.UseBufferedStream = true;
    using (var decompressor = new GZipStream(request.InputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        var decompressedBytes = decompressor.ReadFully();

        // Fails because the MemoryStream, used when UseBufferedStream
        // is true, is not expandable.
        // Or, if we set request.UseBufferedStream = false first, then 
        // it fails because the original HttpInputStream is not writeable.
        request.InputStream.SetLength(decompressedBytes.Length);
        request.InputStream.Write(decompressedBytes, 0, decompressedBytes.Length);
   }
}
PreRequestFilters.Add(Decompress);
```

Is there any way to modify the request body in a PreRequestFilter or RawHttpHandler? Or alternatively, is there a totally different way to implement generic request body decompression for any content type/DTO? The per-request implementation I have working now is fine but it would be interesting to find a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `AppHost.OnPreExecuteServiceFilter()` to change what Request DTO is used to execute your Services with, e.g:

```
class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public virtual object OnPreExecuteServiceFilter(IService service,
        object request, IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes)
    {
        if (httpReq.Headers[HttpHeaders.ContentEncoding]
            .EqualsIgnoreCase(CompressionTypes.GZip))
        {
            //...
            return customRequest;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

### Using a generic ASP.NET HTTP Module

Since this is something that can be genericized at the outer HTTP Protocol layer, an even better option would be to use [generic a GZip HttpModule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14162813/85785), e.g:

```
public class GZipRequestDecompressingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var request = (sender as HttpApplication).Request;

            string contentEncoding = request.Headers["Content-Encoding"];

            if (string.Equals(contentEncoding, "gzip",
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                request.Filter = new GZipStream(request.Filter,
                    CompressionMode.Decompress);
                request.Headers.Remove("Content-Encoding");
            }
        };
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Which can be configured in your **Web.Config** with:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="AnyUniqueName"
            type="YourNamespace.GZipRequestDecompressingModule, YourAssembly"
            preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This would run after ServiceStack's default deserialization (e.g. of JSON requests), right? Thus, I would need to manually deserialize the DTO?

Comment: @esker yeah, have you tried using a `PreRequestFilter`? When you `UseBufferredStream=true`, you should then be able to modify `request.InputStream` which becomes a cached writable MemoryStream of the Request body, that's used for deserialization. Also are you doing this in a SelfHost?

Comment: This is in ASP.NET. I tried exactly that, with UseBufferedStream=true. But if the decompressed data is larger (more bytes) than the compressed data, when I try to write to that stream an exception is thrown indicating that the MemoryStream is "not expandable".

Comment: (The reason the MemoryStream is "not expandable" is because it's initialized using the `MemoryStream(byte[])` [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx))

Comment: @esker No kidding, well that's good to know :). Don't really want to change how it's initialized (as I expect it's more efficient), but I can make BufferedStream writable?

Comment: Are you proposing a change to the ServiceStack source? Is there any merit in adding built-in support for compressed requests while we're at it? Not sure how you would feel about that, as it seems there was a conscious decision not to support automatic compression of responses...

Comment: I could open an Issue on Github to continue this discussion if you prefer.

Comment: @esker Yeah please open an issue, I could make it an option, but I think it'd be cleaner to use a generic [IHttpModule for decompressing all requests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14162813/85785).

Comment: I'm going to use that generic IHttpModule. Thanks for the link, I searched for a more general ASP.NET solution like that and didn't find it.