# How to override GetWebRequest for compressing

Tags: c#, wcf, webrequest

Related To:

[WCF GZip Compression Request/Response Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741768/wcf-gzip-compression-request-response-processing?rq=1)

[Web​Client.​Get​Web​Request(Uri)   Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_GetWebRequest_System_Uri_)

---

I want to do that has been said in the first article. I don't know what does `Proxy Class` means?

I add a WCF web service with name: `MyServiceClient`.

I wrote this code in a class in `APP_Code`:

```
public partial class MyServiceClient : WebClient 
{
    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest rq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        rq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return rq;
    }
}
```

and calling service code:

```
using (ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient())
{
    //Call
    client.MyMethod();
}
```

but when I run this code and call my web service, above code didn't execute.

the second problem is `MyServiceClient` generated automatically by `VS` and it's not `partial`

Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Making your service class derive from `WebClient` doesn't mean it will be invoked as a `WebClient`.

Comment: Thanks but how to rewrite above code to run correctly?

Comment: Try starting here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility/