# Access to request HTTP headers in custom WCF MessageEncoder

Tags: wcf, gzip, wcf-binding, encoder, gzipstream

Does anyone know how to get access to request HTTP headers within MessageEncoder.ReadMessage method?
It seems that WCF already "knows" request headers at the point of invoking ReadMessage method, at least Content-Type and Content-Length but I cannot get the access to the Content-Encoding header.

Basically, I'm trying to utilize gzip de/compression for WCF service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) and would like to check if decompression is necessary for incoming request. To do that I'd like to check Content-Encoding header but cannot figure out where to get it.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A possible solution I have found (it works at least for json/xml binding) is based on the idea that http transport/encoding layer does not pull the whole message at once, so I create MessageProxy that defers decompression/creation of underlying message until somebody tries to inspect the message body. At that point all request headers become accessible. If anyone is interested I can submit the example code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691401/data-compression-for-ado-net-data-services/1724096#1724096) I gave in another thread which explains how you would need to manipulate the headers via the `WebOperationContext` in another `IOperationBehavior` which is coupled with the `MessageEncoder`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand how WebOperationContext and IOperationBehavior could help to setup Content-Encoding header for _outcoming_ message, but I can't figure out how any service, endpoint or operation-wide behaviors could help to access to the _incoming_ message headers.

Comment: Yeah WebOperationContext and OpeationContext are both null for incoming requests